# sudo npm install command not found

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, npm

I have installed `nodejs` and `npm` in my server (os:amazon ami) using node version manager
current node version is `7.10.0`
npm version  is `4.2.0`

nodejs project is located in `var/www/testing` folder when i am trying to install the depeondeies present in package.json using `sudo npm install` i got command not found error

Path of `node` and `npm` is respectively

```
~/.nvm/versions/node/v7.10.0/bin/node

~/.nvm/versions/node/v7.10.0/bin/npm
```

npm and node are in same folder but when I try this command:

`sudo npm install` I got `sudo: npm: command not found`

`npm install` command throws no errors but `node_modules` folder is empty.

Comment: try without `sudo`. Is `node --version` or `npm --version` working?

Comment: can you provide the error please

Comment: @SaugatAcharya `node --version` and `npm --version` working without node it will returns the current node.js and npm versions

Comment: @Natsathorn `sudo npm install` command not found error is thrown

Comment: @Natsathorn sorry this is the correct error message /usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory

Comment: You don't need to do sudo and your installation seems to be correct. Do you have a `package.json` file? If not you'll need one to install dependencies from. Try `npm install react` or something.

Comment: when i try `npm install` i got nothing node_modules folder also my project throwns errors

Comment: @SaugatAcharya my package.json contains  depondies

Comment: What is the error when you do `npm install`?

Comment: Here is the error `Cannot get stack trace in GC.
FATAL ERROR: Scavenger: promoting marked
 Allocation failed - process out of memory
 1: node::Abort() [npm]
 2: 0x12b82ac [npm]
 3: v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(char const*, bool) [npm]
 4: v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*, bool) [npm]
 5: 0xa98e0b [npm]
`

Comment: Your system seems to be out of memory. What do you have in your `package.json`?

Answer (score 2):

Correct npm path is `/usr/local/bin/npm` else just run below command again

```
sudo apt-get install npm
```

And verify the npm is install, Alternatively you can try:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/node /usr/lib/node
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/bin/npm
```

Comment: Which os you are using ? Reinstall it as global

Comment: Amazone linux ami

Comment: For amazon linux AMI just use these commands again 
git clone https://github.com/isaacs/npm.git
cd npm
sudo make install

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I tried to install npm.
bash-3.2$ sudo npm install
sudo: npm: command not found

So, I downloaded node.js from https://nodejs.org/en/
It will automatically set at the required path.

After installation, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try To Install Node Using Nvm  Node Version Manager
From Officai NVM Git Hub Repo

`https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm`

```
git clone https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm
cd nvm
./installer.sh
nvm install <AnyNodeVersion>
```

Now Hit Command Line
This Method Actually Worked For ME

i Face same Issue And Explained It Here
`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67285266/npmcommand-not-found-node-v-is-working-but-for-npm-command-not-found`

Answer (score 0):

Try to hit this command line:

```bash
sudo apt-get install npm
```